# What's the best way to do streaming in your free algebra?

Tags: scala, scalaz, free-monad

I've been experimenting with creating an HTTP client using Free monads, similar to the approach taken in the talk given by Rúnar Bjarnason, [Composable application architecture with reasonably priced monads](https://www.parleys.com/tutorial/composable-application-architecture-reasonably-priced-monads).

What I have so far is can be seen in this snippet, https://bitbucket.org/snippets/atlassian-marketplace/EEk4X.

It works ok, but I'm not entirely satisfied. The biggest pain point is  caused by the need to parameterize `HttpOps` over the algebra it will be embedded in in order to allow streaming of the request and response bodies. This makes it impossible build your algebra by simply saying

```
type App[A] = Coproduct[InteractOps, HttpcOps[App, ?], A]
```

If you try, you get an `illegal cyclic reference` error from the compiler. To solve this, you can use a case class

```
type App0[A] = Coproduct[InteractOps, HttpcOps[App, ?], A]   
case class App[A](app0: App0[A])
```

This solves the cyclic reference problem, but introduces a new issue. We no longer have `Inject[InteractOps, App]` instances readily available, which means we no longer have the `Interact[App]` and `Httpc[HttpcOps[App, ?]]` instances, so we have to [manually define them](https://bitbucket.org/snippets/atlassian-marketplace/EEk4X#Example.scala-50) for our algebra. For a small and simple algebra like this one, that isn't too onerous, but for something bigger it can turn into a lot of boilerplate.

Is there another approach that would allow us to include streaming *and* compose algebras in a more convenient manner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand why `App` needs to refer to itself. What is e.g. the expected meaning of this:

```
App(inj(Send(
  Request(GET, uri, v, hs,
          StreamT(App(inj(Send(
            Request(GET, uri, v, hs,
                    StreamT(App(inj(Tell("foo")))))))))))))
```

That is, an `EntityBody` can for some reason be generated by a stream of HTTP requests nested arbitrarily deep. This seems like strictly more power than you need.

Here's a simple example of using a stream in a free monad:

```
case class Ask[A](k: String => A)
case class Req[F[_],A](k: Process[Ask, String] => A)
type AppF[A] = Coproduct[Ask, Req[Ask,?], A]
type App[A] = Free[AppF, A]
```

Here, each `Req` gives you a stream (`scalaz.stream.Process`) of `String`s. The strings are generated by asking something for the next string (e.g. by reading from standard input or an HTTP server or whatever). But note that the suspension functor of the stream isn't `App`, since we don't want to give a `Req` the opportunity to generate other `Req`s.

Comment: The reason for wanting `App` to be self referential is to allow streaming of different effects. Part of the request body might come from a DB, part might come from a file, part might come from a different DB. I'm also not convinced that composing a request from other requests is too powerful. Imagine a utility to concatenate files in a bucket on S3 and put them in another bucket.

Comment: I think you should parameterize your stream on a monad that may or may not be the App monad. Allowing them to vary independently circumvents your recursion problem and lets you restrict the operations that the thing serving your streams is allowed to do.

Comment: It's not just that you're allowing requests to be composed from other requests. You're allowing the server to require you to execute an arbitrary number of other requests (or responses!) in order to see any given byte vector in its response.

Restriction is your friend. http://blog.higher-order.com/blog/2014/12/21/maximally-powerful/

Comment: Ok, I do like the idea of allowing them to vary. Users can then choose to use a limited set of operations or go the recursive route, if they need it. The only thing that makes me pause is that the, if you have `HttpOps[F, ?]` as part of the algebra `G`, there must be a valid `Inject[F, G]` instance. But that shouldn't be a problem in practice, I believe.

Comment: So I'm revisiting this after some time away - many distractions and changes in life over the past year - and am trying to implement things the way you suggested. So far I've come up with https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5d0b348a91893f044a1d8187c1c4beab but haven't been able to quite figure out how to implement the interpreters. In particular, it seems like `Ask` might been to carry some kind of state with it, like the string it needs to supply or a connection or some other source for the string values. Any thoughts?